# How to add navigation circles to Copenhagen theme in beamer?

Tags: beamer, navigation, circles

I would like to ask if there is a way to add navigation circles to the Copenhagen theme. Let me expalin it better: 
 1. on the left hand side of the header there is a list of the sections.
 2. on the right hand side of the header there is a list of the subsections (if there are any). I don't have subsections.

I would like to have on the right hand side as many navigation circles as frames, situated at the same height as the corresponding section. I saw this configuration in some presentation, but I am unable to replicate it.

As I am unable to show you an example with a real slide, next I show a scketch of how I want the header (each x is for a navigation circle and treat · as white spaces):

|··························|····················|

|···········Section 1 | xxx·············|

|···········Section 2 | xxxxx·········|

|···········Section 3 | xx ··············|

|··························|····················|

Where section 1 has 3 frames, section 2 has 5 frames and section 3 has 2 frames.

Thanks for your help.

Mihaela

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: not quite the same, but might be a starting point: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162786/36296