# How to show navigation bullets in customized Beamer them?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation

I've made my own beamer theme to provide my some resources. I have this code so far:

```
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Malmoe} 
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}

% Command for including frame number in the format #
\newcommand{\framenumber} {
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  {\insertframenumber}}
}

\mode<all>

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[]{subfig}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}

% Command to specify two logos
\newcommand{\logos}[2][]{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
   \vfill
   \rlap{\hskip0.1cm
         \icon[0.5cm]{#1}}
   \vskip2pt% 
} 
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{% 
   \vfill
   \llap{\icon[0.5cm]{#2}\hskip0.1cm}% 
   \vskip2pt
}
}
```

This gives me something like this:

[image]

I would like to show bullets for each frame of a section in the black side of the headline, aligned with the section title. I'm not using the `\subsection` command, so I'm also setting, in the begin of the beamer tex file:

```
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
```

However, I can't see any navigation bullet so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at section 8.2.4 of the beamer manual which says:

> Inside this template, the following inserts are useful:
>
> - \insertslidenavigationsymbol Inserts the slide navigation symbols, that is, the slide symbols (a rectangle) together with arrows to the left and right that are hyperlinked.
> - \insertframenavigationsymbol Inserts the frame navigation symbol.
> - \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol Inserts the subsection navigation symbol.
> - \insertsectionnavigationsymbol Inserts the section navigation symbol.
> - \insertdocnavigationsymbol Inserts the presentation navigation symbol and (if necessary) the ap- pendix navigation symbol.
> - \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol Inserts a back, a find, and a forward navigation symbol.

For example, you can use:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure this answers the question. My feeling is that the OP is looking for miniframes, something close to [Show miniframes with split outer themes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162318/13304).

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, @ClaudioFiandrino. But I should like to show mini frames for each section in vertical lines. I couldn't adapted the solution that you presented, however. :/