# Beamer - How to add progression dots specific for each subsections

Tags: beamer, navigation

is it possibile to add the *progression dots* specific to the subsection?

More specifically i would like to add the dots under the corresponding subsection.

[image]

Here there can be found the codes I used to produce the above.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex, center] {palette quaternary}%
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal {\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}
 \end{beamercolorbox} \\
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{}%
\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal {\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}\\
\end{beamercolorbox}\\ 
  \vspace*{-0.025cm}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}


\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\subsection{subsec. 1.1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 1}\end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 2}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsect. 1.2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 3}\end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 4} \end{frame}


\section{ Section 2}

\subsection{ subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 5}\end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 6}\end{frame}

\subsection{ subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 7}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE does not compile. `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.17 \begin{document}`

Answer (score 1):

I might have came up with a solution: 
it is rather un-elegant but I have played around with some codes I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162318/show-miniframes-with-split-outer-themes) trying to make them working the way I wanted

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged}




\makeatletter

\newcount\beamer@xoff
\newcount\beamer@prev@section
\newcount\beamer@prev@miniframes
\beamer@xoff=0
\beamer@prev@section=0
\beamer@prev@miniframes=0

\def\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontalminiframes#1#2#3{%
  \hbox to #1{{%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]    {subsection in head/foot}%
    \beamer@currentsubsection=0%
    \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1>\beamer@prev@section%
        \beamer@xoff=##3\relax%
        \beamer@prev@miniframes=0\relax%
      \fi
      \ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section%
      \ifnum##2>\beamer@currentsubsection%
      \beamer@xoff=0\relax%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=##2%
      \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex plus1fill%
      \ifnum\beamer@prev@miniframes>0\relax%
        \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
        \multiply\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@prev@miniframes%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
        \ifnum##2>1%
          \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1.875ex%
        \else
          \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
        \fi
      \else
        \beamer@tempdim=0pt%
      \fi
      \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
      \hbox{\def\insertsubsectionhead{\kern\beamer@tempdim##5}%
         \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
         \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##2}%
         \def\insertpartheadnumber{##6}%
         \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
        \beamer@link(##4){{\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}}}\else%
        \beamer@link(##4){{\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}}}\fi}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
      \else%
      \beamer@prev@miniframes=##3%
      \fi%
              \setbox0=\hbox{\insertsectionhead\unskip}\ifdim\wd0>0pt\ifnum##3>0%
      \beamer@xpos=##3\relax%
  \advance\beamer@xpos by -\beamer@xoff%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=0.5pt%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \ifnum##2>0%
        \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
        \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \wd\beamer@sectionbox%
      \else%
        \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
        \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1.875ex%
      \fi%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim\hbox{\beamer@link(##4){%
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=##1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=##3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
      }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}%
  \fi\fi%
  \beamer@prev@section=##1%
  \ignorespaces}%
#2\hskip.3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{}%
\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill\dohead%
\box\beamer@sectionbox\hfil\hskip.3cm%
#3}}}

\setbeamercolor{mini frame}{parent=subsection in head/foot}



\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
 \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}\\

   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{}%
\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontalminiframes{0.9\paperwidth}{}{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
  \\ 

  \vspace*{-0.025cm}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1pt,color=CLE]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\subsection{subsec. 1.1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 1}\end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 2}\end{frame}

\subsection{subsect. 1.2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 3}\end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 4} \end{frame}

\section{ Section 2}

\subsection{ subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 5}\end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 6}\end{frame}

\subsection{ subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Slide 7}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It is a trial-and-error solution, rather than something logical. Take it as is!